# Looking for a Perl Regular Expression that matches the following pattern

Tags: regex, perl

**aa_bb_cc_dd_...** (characters with underscores, one or more )

(or)

**a1_11_1c_1...** (alphanumeric characters with underscores, one or more)

(or)

**aaa...** (just characters, one or more)

Comment: Sure. `.*` will do that. You have to be much more careful about specifying what must be matched *and what must not*. You should also remember that programming is not a job that is best done by asking on the internet for it to be done for you for free. You should always make your own best effort and ask for help with it if you are still struggling after a few hours. Requests for solutions will not usually be answered on *Stack Overflow* unless you are lucky and get someone who is thirsty for reputation points, and such people do not often write great answers.

Comment: `[0-9_]*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*` (e.g. `/^[0-9_]*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*\z/`)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[A-Za-z_0-9]+$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/b4JChY/4)

Comment: Thanks. Your Expression works. But ([a-zA-Z])[A-Za-z_0-9]+ this alone did the job for me.

Comment: @Raveen Kumar, `[a-zA-Z][A-Za-z_0-9]` will match `!a` and `a!`, which shouldn't match according to your question.

Comment: @Raveen Kumar, `^[a-zA-Z][A-Za-z_0-9]\z` won't match `1a`, which should match according to your question.

Comment: @Rizwan M.Tuman, `$` should be `\z`. Your pattern matches the string produced by `"abc\n"`.

Answer (score -1):

**Edited**

If you want to exclude the words which contains only numbers and underscores _ , then try this.

```
(?![_\d]+\b)\w+
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LCxVPB/31)

- (?![_\d]+\b) : means to exclude words which is composed of numbers and underscores only.

Comment: Yes. But it should not match with a number. Only Characters with numbers or characters alone. Along with underscores.

Comment: If you want to exclude the words which contain only numbers and underscores _, then try this.  (?![_\d]+\b)\w+  . I edited above answer for your additional option.